# Fetching first-n elements from multiple sorted partitions

Tags: apache-flink

I want to read multiple files, count repeating lines, sort lines by number of repetitions, take top 10 repeating lines.

```
lines = env.readTextFile("logs-dir")
tuples = lines.map(line -> Tuple2(line, 1))
aggregate = tuples.groupBy(0).sum(1)
sort = aggregate.sortPartition(1, Order.DESCENDING)
sorted.first(10).writeAsText("domains")
```

The problem is that first-n is arbitrary and returns random 10 first elements from all the partitions.

Is there a way to select sorted first-n elements from all the partitions without reducing the parallelism to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this issue with a parallel `MapPartitionFunction` that returns the first 10 elements of each partition, sending the result to a single partition, sorting it and taking the first 10 again. This would look like this:

```
lines = env.readTextFile("logs-dir")
tuples = lines.map(line -> Tuple2(line, 1))
aggregate = tuples.groupBy(0).sum(1)

// sort partitions in parallel
sortPart = aggregate.sortPartition(1, Order.DESCENDING)
// take first 10 of each partition
firstPart = sortPart.mapPartition(new First(10))

// sort all in one partition
sortFull = firstPart.sortPartition(1, Order.DESCENDING).parallelism(1)
// take first 10
first10 = sortFull.mapPartition(new First(10))
first10.writeAsText("domains")
```

The `MapPartitionFunction` `First` would be very simple. It just counts down how many records to forward and returns from the `mapPartition()` function once the counter is down to `0`.